# Haskell: Monads of monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm learning some Haskell and I have some trouble with these Monads, I understood about them and know what they are about but in this particular case I have some issues. While learning it on LYAH I ran across an exercices which was about calculating the positions you could get to in 3 movements with a knight (from the chess game), we used the list monad like this:

Assuming,

```
type KnightPos = (Int,Int)

moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]
moveKnight (c,r) = do
   (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)
              ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)
              ]
   guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
   return (c',r')
```

This works and if I give my position to this function it sucessfuly calculate the possible future positions but now I'm looking to implements the Writer monad in it so I can retrieve how did I get to this point.
So I made this function,

Assuming,

```
type KnightRoute = Writer [KnightPos] KnightPos

moveKnight' :: KnightPos -> [KnightRoute]
moveKnight' (c,r) = do
   (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)
              ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)
              ]
   guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
   return $ toKr (c',r') (c,r)
 where toKr pos oldpos = Writer (pos,[oldpos])
```

It works if I give it a `KnightPos` but using monads I can't extract a `KnightPos` from a `KnightRoute` to execute the function another time...

```
*Main> let a = moveKnight' (2,4) !! 0
*Main> runWriter a
((4,3),[(2,4)])
*Main> a >>= moveKnight'

<interactive>:4:7:
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘Writer [KnightPos]’
Expected type: KnightPos -> Writer [KnightPos] KnightRoute
  Actual type: KnightPos -> [KnightRoute]
In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘moveKnight'’
In the expression: a >>= moveKnight'
```

I understand why it's not working, I extract the `(4,3)` from my Writer but then I give this to `KnightPos'`. But `KnightPos'` returns a list of `KnightRoute` where I need a `KnightRoute`, this is an error of logic but I don't know how to do. Is there a simple way to do this with Monads?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Note that using `Writer` or `WriterT` with lists as the log-monoid is pretty inefficient (quadratic time), because you keep appending to the right. Difference lists or more specialised containers are a better bet.

Comment: I learned about that recently, indeed it seems more efficient to use Difference list. In any cases we should use Difference Lists as log-monoids everytime since it's nothing but faster ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of “combination of two monads” is an extremely common thing in Haskell. Fortunately, the language is flexible enough that we can nicely abstract over this.

Mathematically speaking what you want is a [composition of two functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html). Instead of that newtype, this is usually expressed with the concept of *transformers*: instead of using the `Writer` monad directly, you use the `WriterT` monad transformer. `WriterT w [] a` is [basically the same](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:WriterT) as `[Writer w a]`, so in your case you can use:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer

moveKnight'' :: KnightPos -> WriterT [] [KnightPos] KnightPos
moveKnight'' (c,r) = do
   (c',r') <- lift [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)
                   ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)
                   ]
   guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
   tell [(c,r)]
   return (c',r')
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! I'll look more into monads transformers. I did not know about them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
a' :: Int -> KnightRoute
a' i = a >>= \p -> moveKnight' p !! i
```

Here `i` is used to eliminate the inner list of writers. And, thanks to laziness, you can turn `Int -> a` into `[a]`:

```
asList :: (Int -> a) -> [a]
asList f = map f [1..]
```

Then the list of all routes for `a'` is

```
a's :: [KnightRoute]
a's = asList a'
```

Putting everything together:

```
moveKnight :: KnightRoute -> [KnightRoute]
moveKnight k = map (\i -> k >>= \p -> moveKnight' p !! i) [1..]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks you very much for your answer. I'm sorry I did not understand clearly... did you write pseudo-code ? I can't see what is the variable named "a" for you since you use it as a monad but never define it? Maybe i'm mistaken :)

Comment: @Bryce Tichit, you're welcome. The `a` is meant to be your `a`: `let a = moveKnight' (2,4) !! 0`, i.e. it's just an example. The actual function `moveKnight` works for whatever `KnightRoute` you supply.

Comment: I understand now it is a pretty smart way to do it since it uses laziness, I like this it shows how powerful Haskell is :)